# spark.time() not working for dataframe query

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running this code in `spark-shell`, `spark 2.3.0`:

```
val lineitem=spark.read.parquet("hdfs://namenode:8020/lineitem.parquet")
val decrease = udf { (x: Double, y: Double) => x * (1 - y) }
val increase = udf { (x: Double, y: Double) => x * (1 + y) }
val q1=lineitem.filter($"l_shipdate" <= "1998-09-02")
  .groupBy($"l_returnflag", $"l_linestatus")
  .agg(sum($"l_quantity"), sum($"l_extendedprice"),
        sum(decrease($"l_extendedprice", $"l_discount")),
        sum(increase(decrease($"l_extendedprice", $"l_discount"), $"l_tax")),
        avg($"l_quantity"), avg($"l_extendedprice"), avg($"l_discount"), count($"l_quantity"))
.sort($"l_returnflag", $"l_linestatus")
```

and everything works fine til now. but when I want to measure execution time of query using `spark.time(q1.show())`
I'm getting :

```
    2018-12-22 17:49:56 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID                                                                                         77)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLengt                                                                                        h(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Native Method)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompressedLength(Snappy.java:561)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyD                                                                                        ecompressor.java:62)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(Non                                                                                        BlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
        at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(Byte                                                                                        sInput.java:205)
        at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$Pla                                                                                        inDoubleDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:194)
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$1.initDictionary(Encoding.java:98)
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$4.initDictionary(Encoding.java:149                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnRe                                                                                        ader.<init>(VectorizedColumnReader.java:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetR                                                                                        ecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:312)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetR                                                                                        ecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetR                                                                                        ecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNe                                                                                        xt(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNex                                                                                        t(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIt                                                                                        erator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNex                                                                                        t(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIte                                                                                        ratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIte                                                                                        ratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIte                                                                                        ratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRo                                                                                        wIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$ano                                                                                        n$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(Bypa                                                                                        ssMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scal                                                                                        a:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scal                                                                                        a:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                        java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                        .java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-12-22 17:49:56 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 2.0 in stage 9.0 (TID                                                                                         79)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLengt                                                                                        h(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Native Method)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompressedLength(Snappy.java:561)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyD                                                                                        ecompressor.java:62)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(Non                                                                                        BlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
        at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(Byte                                                                                        sInput.java:205)
```

Any idea what's wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is not related to `spark.time`. The problem is caused by not being able to read the Snappy compressed files. The first block of code you posted is just a transformation, meaning Spark does not actually try to execute it. Remember, Spark uses lazy evaluation.

It is not until you call `q1.show()` that it actually tries to execute query, which triggers the error in reading the Snappy files.

What you really need to troubleshoot is the `lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. There was a recently fixed issue involving a conflict in the Snappy versions used by Spark 2.3.0 and Hadoop 2.8.3:

It seems updating to Spark 2.3.2 fixes the issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24018?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel